# Create Visual Studio Solution From msbuild .proj file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Does anyone know if is possible to have a Visual Studio project created automatically from a msbuild .proj file?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically in my company we have some static libraries that are currently build using nmake, via a msbuild .proj file.  However, they never created a VS sln/vcproj for it.  I would like if there was some way for me to set up a new vcproj based upon the configuration of the proj file.

Comment: Your going to need to share your .proj file.   You can do nearly anything, including make pancakes, with MSBuild proj files

Answer (score 0):

I've just been trying to do something similar.  Basically VS2010 won't let me add a "*.proj" file to a solution.  HOWEVER, I found that if I simply renamed it to be a vbproj or a csproj, then VS2010 would let me add it to a solution, and it seemed to invoke it correctly.  (The vbproj seemed 'nicest' to me, in that it didn't have a redundant "References" sub-folder.)

It does seem odd that VS2010 seems unable to work with an ad hoc MSBuild project file, demanding instead one that is tied explicitly to a specific languade (C#, VB.Net, SQL, WiX, ...)

In my case, it simlpy had an Exec task in it to go and invoke Doxygen to build developer documentation.  That is, it was pretty simple!  I hope the same trick might work for you too!

Another option might be for you would be too look at the "Makefile" project type in VS2010 (its under C++); that would allow you to directly invoke nmake and do away with the proj wrapper completely.